# ProgrammingError at /search/ function similarity

Tags: python, django, postgresql, full-text-search

I am trying to add full text search to my django website, but I am getting this error:

```
ProgrammingError at /search/ function similarity(character varying, unknown) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT SIMILARITY("blog_post"."title",...
```

Here is my `SearchForm`:

```
class SearchForm:
    query = forms.CharField()
```

And here is my `post_search` view function:

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    query = None
    results = []
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['query']
            results = Post.published.annotate(
                similarity=TrigramSimilarity('title', query),
            ).filter(similarity__gt=0.1).order_by('-similarity')
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/search.html',
                  {'form': form,
                   'query': query,
                   'results': results})
```

I am using a Postgres database(version 13.1.1), Django 3.1 and Python 3.7.5

What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you installed the pg_trgm extension in your Postgres DB? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html

Comment: I haven't done that. How can I enable it?

Comment: Read the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigram-similarity there is a migration you can apply to enable it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#django.contrib.postgres.operations.TrigramExtension